# Is there any reference about backpropagation of the Transformer's multi-head layer?

Tags: transformer, backpropagation

Is there any reference about backpropagation of the Transformer's multi-head layer or multi-head attention (MHA)? I have searched various journals but have not found one yet.

Comment: The elements of the multi-head attention block are pretty standard. For those elements, backpropagation is handled without problems by any deep learning framework. What information are you seeking specifically?